# Infragistics UltraToolbarsManager edit ribbonGroups

Tags: toolbar, designer, infragistics

Im just working on my Toolbar,
Im using the `InfragisticsToolbarsManager` and ive created a `Ribbon` with 2 `ribbon groups` in the designer.
You can add groups very easywith this new Group button.
And insert Items with the new Tool button (upper right in the groups)!

But i cant rightclick on it and the property window shows the properties for the wole ultratoolbarmanager.

But i want to know how to edit the `GroupName/Text` ive marked at the screenshot.
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/62849616/InfToolBar.JPG
Atm im doing it at the code of the `Designer.cs` 
but this isnt a real solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UltraToolbarManager properties can be opened right clicking on the UltraToolbarManager control in the bottom pane of your form designer and selecting *'Customize Property Pages'*.
Then select in sequence the **Ribbon** Property, then **Tabs** property, then the appropriate tab index (0 in your example), then the **Groups** property and the specific group (0 and 1 in your example). Inside each group you will find the **Caption** property with the text to change

Comment: Ahh thanks ... i always tried to klick on the 'toolbar' on the 'form' and rightklick but i didnt realize that it is also at the 'bottom pane' just like the 'backgroundworker'

Comment: Glad to be of help. These guys at Infragistics do an exceptional work, but this properties, sometimes, are a labyrinth

Comment: @Steve, I've just started recently with Infragistics and gave up on how to change the group names - Thanks!!! Yes you're right, it's a labyrinth!